# Django REST Framework problem with serializer.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to save some data like Image and it's info with POST method from Postman.
But I got an error: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'.
Here is my code:

1.models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Images(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

2. serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Images

class ImgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ["title", "description", "image"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return ImgSerializer(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

3. views.py

```
class ImgApi(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ImgSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            try:
                serializer.save()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(e)
                return Response(data={'msg':f'{e}'},status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            return Response(data=json_data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And things in Postman:
[image: Things in Postman]

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is from `ImgSerializer.create()` method:

- `serializer.save()` will call `ImgSerializer.create()` because the serializer is not initialized with `instance` keyword.
- In serializer create method, `ImgSerializer(**validated_data)` construct new serializer instance, which will call [`ModelSerializer.__init__`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L108) method. But since you use unpack operator (`**validated_data`), you actually pass `title`, `description` and `image` keyword args to `__init__` method, which are not recognized by the method.

So instead of `ImgSerializer(**validated_data)`, you should use `ImgSerializer(data=validated_data)`.